# Stopping Characters From Being Entered In Form Field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to restrict all symbols from being entered into my form fields in html.

Here is my code...

```
<script>
    $('#location').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

But that code does not allow any spaces or even using the delete key. I want everything to work but don't want any symbols (ie. $#@%^!'"[]{}() etc...)

Comment: You should be able to just change your regular expression to adjust what is and isn't allowed.  If you want it for more than one field, add the fields to your selector `$("#location,#otherField,#otherOtherField).keypress...`

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the invalid characters on `keyup` instead.

```
$('#location').keyup(function(e){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/g, '');
});
```

Otherwise you have to specify the `keyCode` of the keys you want to allow.
http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just get the range of letters and numbers.

48 - 57 (0-9)

65 - 90 (A-Z)

97 - 122 (a-z)

```
<script>
    $('#location').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which < 48 ||
           (e.which > 57 && e.which < 65) ||
           (e.which > 90 && e.which < 97) ||
           e.which > 122) {
           e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This code does not seem to work. It locks up everything, you can't delete, space, or anything.

Comment: @RandyThomas Sorry about that I didnt test I corrected the code should work now